# LDAP integration with activiti

Tags: java, configuration, ldap, activiti

I want to configure ldap with activiti engine,I followed [the activiti user guide](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#chapter_ldap)
but I'm not sure it is working so to test it I want to get all users from Active Directory, can any one help me ?
I'm using activiti 5.21.0 version and java
this is my config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">

  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:activiti;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=1000" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" />
    <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="false" />

     <property name="configurators">
          <list>
              <bean class="org.activiti.ldap.LDAPConfigurator">

                <!-- Server connection params -->
                <property name="server" value="ldap://localhost" />
                <property name="port" value="10389" />
                <property name="user" value="uid=admin, ou=users, o=activiti" />
                <property name="password" value="pass" />

                <!-- Query params -->
                <property name="baseDn" value="o=activiti" />
                <property name="queryUserByUserId" value="((objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid={0}))" />
                <property name="queryUserByFullNameLike" value="((objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(|({0}=*{1}*)({2}=*{3}*)))" />
                <property name="queryGroupsForUser" value="((objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames)(uniqueMember={0}))" />

                <!-- Attribute config -->
                <property name="userIdAttribute" value="uid" />
                <property name="userFirstNameAttribute" value="cn" />
                <property name="userLastNameAttribute" value="sn" />
                <property name="userEmailAttribute" value="mail" />


                <property name="groupIdAttribute" value="cn" />
                <property name="groupNameAttribute" value="cn" />

              </bean>
          </list>
        </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="processEngine" class="org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean">
    <property name="processEngineConfiguration" ref="processEngineConfiguration" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="repositoryService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getRepositoryService" />
  <bean id="runtimeService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getRuntimeService" />
  <bean id="taskService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getTaskService" />
  <bean id="historyService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getHistoryService" />
  <bean id="managementService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getManagementService" />


</beans>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your target LDAP is Active Directory as you suggest, then this line is almost certainly incorrect.

```
<property name="user" value="uid=admin, ou=users, o=activiti" />
```

Active Directory base DN is usually in the format of dc=domain,dc=com whereas eDirectory of often rooted with an Organization object.

The uid=admin node suggests that you are taking this from an example of talking to an OpenLDAP style directory. Default naming in AD is cn=Username (Often cn=First Last in fact).

Comment: ok, Thanks but do you have an idea about how to test it in java ?

Comment: @WassimMakni First of all, fix the DN, and make sure the password is correct, I assume you masked it for public consumption. You want to get an error back from AD that shows why it failed. So wathc your logs, and try with proper DN.

Comment: ok I decided to use apache directory studio as an OpenLDAP the hierarchy is
o=mojo
   ou=groups
      cn=admin
      cn=user
  ou=users

      cn=user1
       cn=user2 etc
can you please suggest me a rectification to my config file

Comment: @WassimMakni So bind DN is cn=admin, ou=Groups, o=mojo if I read you correct.  Base DN would then be ou=Users,o=mojo?  Use an LDAP browser to look at your tree and see what the proper distinguished names of the target objects (DN of Admin user, and DN of container that holds the Users).

Comment: this how my tree  [looks like](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByQ8yIFFMhoEUmYwempCT0tOMUE/view?usp=sharing) so i think this line 
`<property name="user" value="uid=admin, ou=users, o=activiti" />`
will be 
`<property name="user" value="o=mojo" />` because i want to get all the elements inside mojo